# Java get value from log file with multiple delimiters

Tags: java, regex, logging, split, readfile

I have a log file and first line of it: `**99.91.220.138 - - [05/Oct/2015:06:37:26 +0300] "GET /R/0A/ID_0000013091.ism/QualityLevels(1469889)/Fragments(video=14795200000) HTTP/1.1" 200 658377 "-" "Firefox/1.5" "-" rt=0.000 ut="-" cs=HIT**` I want to seperate this line and print them :

- **User ip**:99.91.220.138
- **Event time**:[05/Oct/2015:06:37:26 +0300]
- **Request    method**:GET
- **Content adress**:    /R/0A/ID_0000013091.ism/QualityLevels(1469889)/Fragments(video=14795200000)
- **Content name**: ID_0000013091
- **Content bitrate i**:    QualityLevels(**1469889**)  I try to write just 1400000
- **Content type:**    Fragments(**video**=14795200000) Video or Audio
- **HTTP Status**: 200
- **Total sent Bytes**: 658377
- **User Agent:** Firefox/1.5
- **Cache Status**:    cs={STATUS} : HIT (Cache used), MISS(cache is not used)

after reading this information I will insert them to the mssql database.

HOW CAN I PRINT THEM?

I try  `String pattern = "\\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] (\\S) \\[(\\w+) ([\\d.]+) ([\\d.]+) (\\w+) (\\w+.*)\\] (\\w.*?\\d{3}) ([\\d.]+) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" (\\S) (\\w+) (.*)";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);`

```
    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find( )) {
        System.out.println("String: " + m.group(0) );
        System.out.println("IP: " + m.group(1) );
        System.out.println("Event time: " + m.group(2) );
        System.out.println("Request Method: " + m.group(3) );
        System.out.println("Content adress: : " + m.group(4) );
        System.out.println("Content name: " + m.group(5) );
        System.out.println("Content bitrate i: " + m.group(6) );
        System.out.println("Content type: " + m.group(7) );
        System.out.println("HTTP Status: " + m.group(8) );
        System.out.println("Total sent Bytes: " + m.group(9) );
        System.out.println("User Agent: " + m.group(10) );
        System.out.println("Cache Status: " + m.group(11) );
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
```

but it does not help me`where is my mistake in the pattern or others?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I added my question

Comment: Hint: Use regular expressions.

Comment: I use this code but I have problems with them.